# When to split users into several Devise models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an Rails app with two types of users: customers and suppliers. Each type has access to completely different controllers.

I'm in doubt know if I create one Devise model or two.

Are there any conventions when to use more than one controller in Devise?

I know that this is a general question and very subjective. Nevertheless I would like to know if there is any official guidelines for this? This question has been keeping me thinking for a long time already.

If there eis any forum on SE that is more appropriated for this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that your `customers` and `suppliers` have some things in common (username and password, logging in to your site, etc), but they are just able to access different controllers/views/features etc. If you were to create two Devise models, it seems like you'd be creating a bunch of repetition.

This seems like a great fit for role-based authorization. There's a nice description of role-based authorization in the [cancan docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization): even if you're not using cancan, their docs give some nice examples that could be a starting point for a larger conversation.